# Widetilde and prime (derivative) position

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, amsmath

I need to write something like `{\widetilde f}'` in my text, but the result looks rather ugly since the prime (derivative) sign is too low. It looks like `\widetilde{f'}`.

Is there any way to do this properly?

Comment: Why not `\tilde{f'}`?

Comment: I'd use `$\tilde{f}'$`, so there wouldn't be any ambiguity about it being the derivative of “tilde f” and not ”tilde of the derivative of f”.

Comment: @egreg: I just prefer \widetilde, but maybe it is indeed better to use `\tilde` in this case.

Comment: @xen You shouldn't prefer `\widetilde`; for lowercase letters there's no need for it (and rarely also for uppercase ones).

Comment: @egreg: Oh, thanks. I didn't know that and I've got used to `\widetilde`. Although (maybe just for me) even with `\tilde` it sometimes doesn't look good to write something like `\tilde{f}^n`. This `n` "should" be over `\tilde`, or maybe I'm just wrong here?

Comment: @xen, let TeX do the job for you. Don't worry with the position. type it as simples as possible.

Comment: @xen I don't think the exponent should be raised in case of $\tilde{f}^n$; the decoration is understood to apply to the letter; `\widetilde` is there just for the different case `\widetilde{f^n}`, so one can clearly see what the decoration applies to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd avoid `\widetilde`, particularly above an “f”. A decoration (math accent) above a symbol is usually interpreted as a modifier of the symbol itself, so

```
$\tilde{f}'$
```

will be interpreted as “the derivative of f tilde”, rather than “tilde of the derivative of f”.

Should you feel that an ambiguity could arise, it's probably better to add parentheses

```
$(\tilde{f})'$
```

rather than raising the prime that could be mistaken for some “tilde prime”.

Below I show some examples.

[image]

As you see, raising the prime is not the answer.

Comment: Many thanks! I just have one question. In comments you said about `\widetilde`: "for lowercase letters there's no need for it (and rarely also for uppercase ones)". Are there any "rules" when I should use `\widetilde`?

Comment: @xen Generally, `\widetilde` should be used only for decorating a group of symbols.